# how i read new line in integer type input

Tags: c

how i take input in this problem.

The input consists of multiple lines.
The first line contains a number n which indicates that the number of rows in the Pascal’s triangle will be n+1 (Note that rows of Pascal’s triangle are indexed starting with 0 at the top and the elements in a row are also indexed starting with a 0).
The second line contains a number m which indicates the number of transactions to be performed on the Pascal’s triangle. Each transaction is given in a separate line.  A transaction is a space separated list of integers. The first integer in each list indicates the row number, say R, and the rest of the integers in the list indicate the indices of values in row R. For each transaction, you have to compute the sum of given coefficients in the given row R.
Input will be given in the following format:

5

3

3 1 2

5 1 1 1 4

4 2 3 2

Comment: Use `scanf("%d",&num);`. It'll automatically skip blanks like spaces and `\n`. Or you can use `fgets()`. It'll read a whole line and also include the `\n` in it. You can use `sscanf()` to extract numbers from the line scanned by `fgets()`. BTW,if the title is your question,then the answer would be "you can't do that"(by "integer type input",I assume you thought about `%d`). I've explained why you can't do that in the second sentence of this comment.

Comment: What's your question?  It looks like you're just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: i want read when new line occur , so i identify  it is defferent command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will read all ints from standard input, skipping space and newline.

```
while(1) {
    int ch = getc(stdin);
    if(ch == EOF) break;
    if(ch == '\n') {
        printf("NewLine ......\n");
    }

    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    int x;
    if(scanf("%d", &x) == EOF) break;
    printf("READ:%d:\n", x);
}
```

Comment: how detect when user pressed enter.

Comment: Edited the answer to read for Newlines. I have given a printf at the place where it sees Newline

Comment: but how i store the integers.

Comment: It is already stored in x for now. You can use it the way you want to.

Comment: here why taking character in "int ch"